# Image rectification using rectifyStereoImages in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst

i want to rectify two stereo image captured by two cameras. I want to do the rectification using the MATLAB function rectifyStereoImages:

[rectifystereoimages](http://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/rectifystereoimages.html)

My Problem is that the stereoParams which I computed using [stereoCameraCalibrator](http://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/stereocameracalibrator-app.html?searchHighlight=stereoCameraCalibrator) are not accepted by the function:

[J1,J2] = rectifyStereoImages(I1,I2, stereoParams)

Here is the code snippet:

```html
imPath1 = 'Webcam1_00001.jpg';
imPath2 = 'Webcam2_00001.jpg';
imW1 = imread(imPath1);
imW2 = imread(imPath2);

load stereoParams.mat;

[I1, I2] = rectifyStereoImages(imW1, imW2, stereoParams);
```

Running this leads to the output:

> Attempt to execute SCRIPT rectifyStereoImages as a function:
>   /home/.../rectifyStereoImages.m
>
> Error in rectifyStereoImages (line 8)
>   [I1, I2] = rectifyStereoImages(imW1, imW2, stereoParams);

I think the loaded variable stereoParams is OK but I can not see what the problem is.

Hope you have some idea.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of MATLAB do you have?  Also, what happens when you type in `which rectifyStereoImages` in the command prompt?  What do you get on your screen?

Comment: <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    dasdadasda

<!-- end snippet -->



> which rectifyStereoImages
results to: /home/..../rectifyStereoImages.m. My created m-file.

Now I changed the name to rectifyStereoPhotos.m

Running returns no problems, but a warning and the rectified output images are black? Do you know why it results to black images?

Here is the warning:

Comment: Warning:The undistorted image may contain invalid pixels. This may be caused by inaccurate calibration. Try
calibrating with more images, so that the calibration patterns cover most of the field of view.> In cameraParameters>cameraParameters.getValidBounds at 1004 In cameraParameters>cameraParameters.computeUndistortBounds at 930 In stereoParameters>stereoParameters.computeOutputBounds at 607
  In stereoParameters>stereoParameters.computeRectificationParameters at 508 In stereoParameters>stereoParameters.rectifyStereoImagesImpl at 260 In rectifyStereoImages at 99 In rectifyStereoPhotos at 8

Comment: MATLAB Version: R2014b (8.4.0.150421), 64-bit, September 15, 2014

Comment: Press "edit" and update your question, don't add this information in comments.  The problem, now you've fixed the filename issue, is more likely in how you did the calibration, but check the `type` and `max`/`min` values of the output images in case it's a scaling issue.

Comment: Yes please add this information to your post.  Also, you don't need the snippet blocks.  MATLAB is not JavaScript syntax so it's not going to render properly.

Comment: Getting the type of the output images results to some unreasonable and unreadable result.

'type Output1.jpg' -> '���� JFIF �� C ..... ' AND
'type Output2.jpg' -> '���� JFIF �� C ..... '

For both images max -> 117 and min -> 46.

I dont understand what to do with this results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving the problem:

1. own calibration implemented
2. using [I1, I2] = rectifyStereoImages(imW1, imW2, stereoParams,'OutputView','full'); instead of [I1, I2] = rectifyStereoImages(imW1, imW2, stereoParams);

Thank you for you help and suggestions!